# How to reset Terminal after seeing "Process Completed"

Tags: julia

I'm on a Mac. Suppose I open Julia in Terminal (REPL). Then I type `ctrl+d`and get

```
[Process Completed]
```

Then I can't use the Terminal window anymore! Is there any way to "reset" the window, or do I have to open a new one? This also happens if I run a simple program:

```
$ echo 'println(PROGRAM_FILE); for x in ARGS; println(x); end' > script.jl
$ julia script.jl foo bar
script.jl
foo
bar

[Process completed]
```

Edit: To clarify the question a bit: I can enter python:

```
$ python
>>>
```

Then I hit `ctrl+d` and am returned back to the shell in the same window, which I can now reuse. But doing the same in julia basically just quits the window.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with julia but I don't have a mac to test it on. If you do ctl-D in a terminal on a mac (without running any program) it gives you the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't realize that. But I guess the second part of my question still stands - it seems to be the default behavior of julia programs (at least simple ones) to do the same thing, and I'm wondering if it's possible to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with julia. In the mac terminal, ctrl-d closes down the shell. If you run a simple julia program, it should return to the command prompt when finished. Example:

In a file called `foo.jl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

x = 2+2
println(x)
```

Now in the terminal:

```
$ julia foo.jl
4
$
```

Your julia script might be hanging, forcing you to kill it. You might try `ctrl-c` (to kill it) or `ctrl-z` (to pause it and move it to the background) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, when I was running Julia from the Launchpad.

Then I added julia's directory to the path.

run in terminal:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin:$PATH"
```

and add the line:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bash_profile`

Now when I run Julia from the terminal I can close it without problems using `ctrl-D`

But when I launch Julia from Launchpad the same problem is still present.